# Building a request processor for multi-page forms, etc using $_GET requests

Tags: filters, redirect, actions, forms

Good day,
What I'm trying to accomplish in a semi-elegant way today is building a multi-step form type thing. Essentially, I'm trying to rewrite the page based on a $_GET request. Like, say, it's /fred?step=2 and /fred is where the shortcode for this plugin is located...

Here's some dummy code I wrote up that gives you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish. This is in my main plugin file, and while it works, I know it's definitely not the right way...

```
add_action('init', 'router');
function router() {
    $dash = (isset($_GET['dash'])) ? $dash = $_GET['dash'] : $dash = '';
    $dash = sanitize_text_field( $dash );

    if ('thing' == $dash) {   
        add_filter('the_content', 'thing'); 
    }

    if ('stuff' == $dash) {
       add_filter('the_content', 'stuff');  
    }
}

function thing() {
    ob_start() ?>
        <h1>THIS IS A THING!!!</h1>
    <?php return ob_get_clean();
}

function stuff() {

    ob_start() ?>
        <h1>THIS IS THE STUFF!!!</h1>
    <?php return ob_get_clean();
}
```

I'd appreciate any advice on how to actually do this the right way. 
Thanks!